# $A\cap B^c\cap C^c$ = $A \cap (B \cup C)^c$?

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

Let, A, B and C be events in Sample Space S:

Describe the event "Only A occurs."

The book answer is: $A\cap B^c\cap C^c$

But I thought $A \cap (B \cup C)^c$ would work?

I'm guessing this means $B^c\cap C^c$ = $(B \cup C)^c$?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. You are looking at De Morgan's laws (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: Thanks @Rodrigo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, $B^c\cap C^c$ = $(B \cup C)^c$ which follows from De Morgan's law for sets. The intersection of the complements of the sets is equal to the complement of the union of the sets.

Comment: Thanks for commenting! Not sure why you got downvoted? Is it correct to use the terms sum and product here?

Comment: @CormJack not, you are right. Sry, eng is not my language. Ill fix that

Comment: Okay if you can fix the language, I'll vote it back so you're at least at zero lol. I hate when new people are down voted here! Thanks for answering!

Comment: @CormJack No problem. Theres also law $B^c\cup C^c$ = $(B \cap C)^c$, so remember that. These both laws are very useful in operations on sets and in logic.

Comment: Awesome thanks!